# Possible short between red and black but no continuity

Tags: hvac

I am tapping into an existing 12/2 circuit. I ran 12/3 to a gang box to wire a fan/light combo with separate switches. I am connecting two single throw switches to the hot using pigtails and the other side of one switch goes to red and the other switch to black of the 12/3.  I’m connecting the neutral and grounds from 12/2 to 12/3 romex respectively.  The fan/light side is not connected but in the box with each wire individually wire nutted.

When I turn on either switch or both switches, both red AND black get power.  When I used a multimeter, the incoming power and the appropriately switched power are 120V between hot and neutral or hot and ground. Not voltage between neutral and ground.  But it appears red will get about 50V when black switched on and black will get 50-70V when red switched on.

When I have switches off, or red and black disconnected, I do not get continuity between black and red or any other combo when measured from the fan box.  I checked from both sides in case a short was close to one end. If I wire nut red and black together on one end, I get continuity between red and black on the other side so my meter works correctly.

Where the wire is run should be out of the way and protected from anything screwed into the wall. There is one section that a towel rack was added to a wall and MAYBE it could have contacted a wire bc I don’t recall the exact path of the wire as it was done two years ago.

Is it possible I could have a short somehow that allows partial voltage between red and black but not enough to show continuity between them?

I’ve disconnected everything to be safe.

Comment: Possible a partial short or just phantom power.  If no continuity between them then phantom power is more likely.  A nail/screw should show at least some resistance/continuity  reading between red and black.

Comment: Probably just capacitive coupling. High-impedance digital voltmeters can give misleading readings on open-ended conductors. Connect a small load (such as an incandescent bulb in a socket with pigtails) and measure the voltage across it.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely this is just phantom power (high-impedance meter reading voltage that's coupled between wires without a transformer core.) It has voltage only becasue nothing is connected - with something connected, a few microamps will flow to neutral and the voltage will go away.

If you had a short you'd see ful voltage on both the shorted together wires, and you'd see continuity or less than infinite resistance between them.

Connect a load (on both wires, or if you want to drag the process out, to the wire you haven't switched on) and watch the phantom power go away. If it *doesn't* go away, *then* you might have a problem, and you can update your question.

Comment: Yup, it's phantom voltage.  Poor quality measuring device.

Comment: Interesting. Ok. That makes sense. 

What load can I add to both wires that will be enough to prove this?  

The load side is currently just in a junction box until I have time to run wire to the ceiling fan/light. It’s in a single gang box right now. Can I simply add an outlet to each or do I need something with actual amperage draw?  I could run two outlets or an outlet and break the tab then plug something in to each if need be.

Comment: An outlet with nothing plugged in (and turned on, if it has a switch) is still a disconnected wire. There needs to be something there that would turn on if you power it on. Doesn't need to be much - a phone charger would do.

Answer (score 1):

The electricity emits EM. Electro magnetic field.

Same as your radio station, same as your phone.

Those waves travel true the air or vacuum, and you can receive them on your device antenna. Antenna is nothing more than a isolated pice of metal that is bombarded by EM waves.

Same occurs with your copper wires. If one of them is isolated (not connected to anything) it will act as antenna.

The Digital Volt meter uses very high resistance (resistor), so it does not consumes (drains) almost any current and the charge stays.

Some call it phantom voltage, well it is not phantom, it is there, but with very very low current.